# Как передать переменную из Python в Javascript Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('captcha_response').value ='content'")

Постоянно получаю исключения, как правильно передать переменную в параметр value из python в js selenium
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('captcha_response').value ='content'")
```